# How do I hook and execute cleanup commands in a GitHub Action when someone cancels the job?

Tags: github-actions, building-github-actions

I'm creating an action (using [actions/javascript-actions](https://github.com/actions/javascript-action)) that creates something and then needs to clean up that something should someone cancel the job halfway.

I'm having trouble finding how to hook into pre-exit/cancel and do cleanup actions. Is this possible? Does anyone have any suggestions on achieving this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally figured it out. [actions/checkout](https://github.com/actions/checkout) is a great example of the [post "runs"](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/creating-actions/metadata-syntax-for-github-actions#post) to achieve this.

```
runs:
  using: node12
  main: dist/index.js
  post: dist/index.js
```